# Execute SSIS package using command prompt with multiple parameters

Tags: asp.net, ssis, business-intelligence

How to execute SSIS package using command prompt with multiple parameters and how to schedule it using task scheduler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the package is in file system, Right click on package,Click Open with Execute Package Utility.
 On the left menu, You will need to set values as needed in "Connection Managers", "Set Values" tabs and others as needed.
 Finally, the "Command Line" will give you all the text needed for parameters.
 Insert a DTEXEC before that text and you are ready to execute in Command Line.

You can store that in a cmd/bat file and execute it with Task Scheduler.